# Does rebase lose PR conversations on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I want to rebase to add GPG signatures to some historic commits. Can I do this with the preserve merge option and still retain all my PR conversations in GitHub?

Comment: you could make a sacrificial branch & pull request to test it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the changes as a fixup commit but don't rebase while the review is underway. This will allow the PR to continue without losing context. Your reviewers will be able to see just the addition of the signatures in the fixup commit(s).

Once the PR is approved, then you can rebase -i --autosquash which will squash those fixup commits into the correct places.